# Overlapping Views in Android

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

Is it possible to have overlapping views in Android? I would like to have an ImageView with a transparent png in the front and another view in the background.

edit:

This is what I have at the moment, the problem is that the image in the imageView is not transparent, the parts that should be transparent are just black.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gallerylayout"
>
<Gallery android:id="@+id/overview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

 <ImageView android:id="@+id/navigmaske"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/navigmask"
    /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

edit:

I got it to work, it was a theme file from another programmer on the team.
Just changed this

```
<item name="android:background">#FF000000</item>
```

to this

```
<item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
```

Comment: What you've got should work -- Are you sure the Gallery has visible contents and that the navigmaske drawable is a PNG with transparency?

Comment: Yes, the gallery is visibile without the overlay and I'm sure that the PNG is transparent

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Android handles transparency across views and drawables (including PNG images) natively, so the scenario you describe (a partially transparent `ImageView` in front of a `Gallery`) is certainly possible.

If you're having problems it may be related to either the layout or your image. I've replicated the layout you describe and successfully achieved the effect you're after. Here's the exact layout I used.

```
<RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/gallerylayout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <Gallery
    android:id="@+id/overview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/navigmaske"
    android:background="#0000"      
    android:src="@drawable/navigmask"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/overview"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/overview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that I've changed the parent `RelativeLayout` to a height and width of `fill_parent` as is generally what you want for a main Activity. Then I've aligned the top and bottom of the `ImageView` to the top and bottom of the `Gallery` to ensure it's centered in front of it.

I've also explicitly set the background of the `ImageView` to be transparent.

As for the image drawable itself, if you put the PNG file somewhere for me to look at I can use it in my project and see if it's responsible.

Comment: Nice! I tried setting an ImageView background to #0000 (and @android:color/transparent) … to no avail. If I try to fade it (alpha from 1.0 down to 0.0) it fades to black instead of fading to transparent. This is on Android 2.0.

Comment: A-ha! I was using LinearLayout. I changed it to Relative, then put the ImageView last. Now the fade "just works" … yay! Thanks tons for the code/tip. That cued me as to my goof.

Comment: Hi im using same xml layout coding but my transparent image is not displayed.It shows only black screen. Anything i want to add in my code.

Comment: Considering the functionality, I'd say `FrameLayout` should be preferred in general for such purposes, for the sake of the much lower layout overhead. However, for API < 11, FrameLayout can't handle the above combination of propagating the second child's height to the first child correctly, so `RelativeLayout` is your only option in this case; [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15780884/1856738).

Answer (score 9):

Also, take a look at `FrameLayout`, that's how the Camera's Gallery application implements the Zoom buttons overlay.

Comment: I've always gone for `FrameLayout` which I find perfect for such purposes. However, I only now found out that prior to API 11, `FrameLayout` fails to propagate the maximum measured height to all of its children, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15780884/1856738). Hence, for supporting Android 2, one has to use `RelativeLayout` unless one goes for a predetermined height.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to add your custom Overlay screen on Layout, you can create a Custom Linear Layout and get control of drawing and key events. You can my tutorial- Overlay on Android Layout-
http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/08/overlay-on-android-layout.html

Comment: Certainly a nice experiment, thank you for sharing the code. But this can simply be achieved with `FrameLayout` unless your specific scenario is affected by a pre-API 11 bug, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15780884/1856738), in which case you still can use `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

A visible gallery changes visibility which is how you get the gallery over other view overlaps. the Home sample app has some good examples of this technique.

Answer (score 1):

The simples way arround is to put -40dp margin at the buttom of the top imageview

Answer (score 0):

Now with Jetpack Compose in android, you should use Box for overlapping views.
Example.

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight()){
        RecipesList(viewModel.recipes.value)
        Snackbar()
    }
```

Here RecipesList and Snackbar are composabes positioned one on top of the other in the composition order

Check out this for Jetpack Compose samples - https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2021/08/03/jetpack-compose-1-0-0-sample-codes/

Answer (score -3):

Yes, that is possible. The challenge, however, is to do their layout properly. The easiest way to do it would be to have an AbsoluteLayout and then put the two images where you want them to be. You don't need to do anything special for the transparent png except having it added later to the layout.

Comment: AbsoluteLayout is now depreciated. Nobody should use it anymore.