# How to stop OpenGL ES drawing background color on Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Now I want to insert a ImageView behind the GLSurfaceView.But the GLSurfaceView always draws background color so I can't see the ImageView.I tried `glClearColor(0,0,0,0)` but it doesn't work.What should I do?Please help me!
Thank you very much.

Comment: why do you want to have an extra view with you opengl, why not simply draw your image in the background of your opengl View ?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you should be able to adapt this

[Overlapping Views in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961944/overlapping-views-in-android)

to your needs

(relative layout and android:background="#0000")

since GLSurfaceView is a View it should work.

Comment: I'm sorry.I did gLSurfaceView.setBackgroundColor(color.transparent);   But it didn't work :(

Comment: What layout are you using ? I think if your not using and relative layout it won't do the transparency (otherwise I have no ideas sorry)

Comment: Now I fixed it using "gLSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);" Thank you very much:XD

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.
using

```
    gLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8,8,8,8,16,0);
    gLSurfaceView.setRenderer(this);
    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
    BgLayout bgl = new BgLayout(this);
    gLSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    gLSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    rl.addView(bgl);
    rl.addView(gLSurfaceView);
```