# displaying one image on the top of another in android

Tags: android, image, canvas, bitmap

I am developing a small game. I have displayed an image as the background and now want to display another image in the bottom middle of the scree. Any ideas how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961944/overlapping-views-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FrameLayout for your purpose , If you have set background to layout , Use imageview and position it.

Check here , Though it talks about merging layouts and optimization , there is a good example of using FrameLayout.
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html