# Android: Draw image over button

Tags: android, image, button, view, lighting

Is it possible to draw an image over another view (like a button) and still have the view work normally? The user would still be able to click on the button even though there is another image on top of it.  I want to draw some mostly transparent pngs over my layout for lighting effects, but I want to make sure everything will still work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `RelativeLayout` with an `ImageView` on top of the widget(s) in your app. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961944/overlapping-views-in-android) for a quick example.