# How to make a ProgressBar stay in the center of screen despite scrolling

Tags: android, vertical-alignment

I have a ProgressBar in a ScrollView, and I'd like it to stay centered vertically despite the user scrolling down or up. However, I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Here's the code that I have, simple as it is. I have an indeterminate ProgressBar:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/ocr_scroll_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/image_holder"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And I call it as such:

```
    spinningProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    spinningProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    spinningProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Setting its visibility at the appropriate times.

All suggestions very much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put it outside of the ScrollView. Just have the ScrollView and the ProgressBar overlap.

You can read about how to overlap views here: [Overlapping Views in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961944/overlapping-views-in-android)

There's a couple of ways to do it, ranging from GridLayouts to RelativeLayouts and then programatic ways to do it.

Comment: Great idea. However, as the ScrollView is the highest view, I'd need to create a new layout outside of it to hold the ProgressBar, wouldn't I?

Comment: OH. Yes - just put them both inside of a RelativeLayout. Then you can use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to make the ProgressBar be in the center of the layout.

Comment: Hell yes, works like a charm. Though the ProgressBar had to come after the ScrollView in order to be visible, which I neglected in my first attempt. And then I got a strange classcast error, but rebuilding the project did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully adding another View as a holder won't do anything significant toward Activity efficiency, shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: @mikeappell it won't do anything. you won't notice anything from something as small as that

Answer (score 9):

You need the ScrollView to be at same level as ProgressDialog in your Layout.

Here it is in concept:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ProgressDialog>      
    <ScrollView>      
<RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have to downvote this - this won't actually work, as the progress bar has to be drawn AFTER the scrollview...

Comment: Alex K - you are right, I did change the order in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can insert this into the scrollview tag

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```