# How to Add Layout on the Top of another Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How to bring layout or view on the top of another view or layout 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht8e1.png)as shown in the picture

Comment: you need something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961944/overlapping-views-in-android ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want exactly?
See you can do it in two way:

1. Take a `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` inside it take a `Relative Layout` then take a `Textview` and `RelativeLayout with an ImageView` inside it. Align the `RelativeLayout with ImageView` on the right side and the `TextView` to the left of it.
2. Take a `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` and below it take a `RelativeLayout with ImageView` and align it to `Right and Top`